# Ruling on working in a logistic/shipping service company

Tags: halal-haram, work

So i've been working in this company that ships goods/documents, I receive the goods, weight the goods and receive the payment/shipping fees from the customer, but the things is the company has procedure of rounding the weight lets say, 0,1kg - 1,3kg will be rounded to 1kg, anything more will be rounded to the next kilogram so if customer wants to ships documents weighed 0.1 kg he will have to pay a shipping fee for a 1kg. note that the company have published this terms on their social media but im not sure every customer awares of it, what is the ruling of salary i received from this job? and what if one doesnt work directly in this processes such as as an IT Helpdesk in the same company.

Comment: Having pricing ranges for certain products/services is a common thing in business. Unless the company displays/tells price X, but charges price Y for a service, in other words, unless they are not charging what they said they will charge, I don't see an issue here. Whether the customers check the terms and fine print are their responsibility, but the company should make such pricing information publicly available, or provide if asked by customers. Why did you feel like it might not be ok?

Comment: because of Surah Hud 85 and Al-Mutafiffin 1-6 .

Comment: What you described, in my understanding, does not fit into the category of the verses you mentioned, which refer to incorrect measurements in trading. In your case, if I understood correctly, the company openly informs customers that they will ship an item for X price, if it weighs 0.1kg to 1.3kg. They will ship for Y price if it weighs 1.31kg to 2.3kg etc. There's nothing wrong in that. However, if the customer wants to ship an item that weighs 0.6kg, but the company weighs it as 1.6kg intentionally and applies the 1.31-2.31kg pricing to it, then that is an unfair dealing.

Comment: Jazakallah Khairan brother for your comment. I also inform them about the procedure directly if I was the one that handle the goods as a precaution measure. They never complained and some even joke about it.